# Remove duplicate field by Max Order_id and sort by maximal

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'HELLO';
        'nid' => '50',              //////DUPLICATE
        'Order_id' => '240',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'My View';
        'nid' => '51',
        'Order_id' => '220',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'HELLO';
        'nid' => '50',              //////DUPLICATE
        'Order_id' => '200',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'Starts';
        'nid' => '54',
        'Order_id' => '195',
      ),
    )
```

I need to remove duplicate Arrays by using `Max Order_id` and sort by maximal `Order_id` In this example.

Any help on doing this?

Comment: Was there a typing mistake since Order ID of arrays marked duplicate are different i.e., 240 and 200.

Comment: And are you trying to remove the arrays having duplicate 'nid's or arrays that match completely?

Comment: Not mistae..2 field with same NID and same Title, every time user has new order ORDER_ID is UPDATED and added New ORDER_ID, so cause to dublicate fields....!

Comment: I want to remove complete OLD Array with old ORDER_ID and just show the new Arrays with new ORDER_ID

Comment: Have you tried something? You can start by looking up usort on php.net and then array_fillter

Comment: i am trying fix this problem with PHP or DB query  or....

Comment: Please explain *in the question(!)* when 2 entries are considered duplicates. What exactly makes them duplicate? Their `nid` value alone? Their `nid` and `title` combination? Their `title` alone?

Comment: I have an array (In fact, my array is derived query from the database DB_SELECT ) that some of them duplicated and all duplicate arrays are Same Title and Nid, but only Order_ID field is different and I want to avoid duplicate it with remove duplicate Arrays with just highest index ORDER_ID is kept.

Comment: look my array plan in Snippet http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a7366d30cad7087f02362da0b2f4f1b0dd010a71

Comment: Please provide desired output for that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by storing the data into an associative array keyed by `nid` values: if you do this in order of increasing `Order_id` you will be left with the most "recent" values per `nid`

If your data is in `$array`:

```
// Sort by Order_id
array_multisort(array_column($array, "Order_id"), $array);
// Keep one entry per nid
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $hash[$row["nid"]] = $row;
}
// Convert back to indexed array:
$result = array_values($hash);
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/907518)

Comment: It works in the link I provided. Could you provide a link where it does not work, and explain me what is wrong with it?

Comment: In this method, the loop is repeated several times !! but work , how remove duplicate arrays !

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Please provide a test case with input *and desired output*.

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for help me for fixing my problem ...my mistake is unclose While :D 
Thanks stackoverflow !